# Python asyncio script received one Modbus TCP packet from three

Tags: python, python-asyncio, modbus-tcp

I want to read data from some device I havn't got yet. So, I use Modbus Poll to test my Python program and that program get only 1 packet from 3. I copied Example script and it get only 1 packet from 3 too. What's wrong an how to fix it to get all packets?
Here the program:

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):

    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 5020)
    for i in range(0,len(server.sockets)):
        addr = server.sockets[i].getsockname()
        print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()    

await main()
```

And here the output:

```
Serving on ('127.0.0.1', 5020)
Received '\x001\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\n' from ('127.0.0.1', 50298)
Send: '\x001\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\n'
Close the connection
Received '\x004\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\n' from ('127.0.0.1', 50299)
Send: '\x004\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\n'
Close the connection
Received '\x007\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\n' from ('127.0.0.1', 50300)
Send: '\x007\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\n'
Close the connection
```

x001, x004, x007 - Transaction Identifiers, they must be x001, x002, x003, x004, x005, x006, x007.

Halp! :\

upd: I checked by WireShark - sender send x001, x002, x003, x004, x005, x006, x007 packets.

Comment: Are you sure that the sender is actually using consecutive transaction ID numbers?  As far as I can tell, there is no requirement for this, they simply need to be distinct.

Comment: No, I don't sure. But sender indicating Errors during the exchange.